# Rotate object to face a direction in a duration in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions, euler-angles

So, in my scene I have my main game object, and a second game object which serves as a reference. I want the main game object to rotate so that it will face the same way as the second game object. And this rotating needs to happen in a set time. Let's presume the duration is 3 seconds. If the second game object has a world rotation of 0, 90, 0, the main game object starts to rotate so that after three seconds it's rotation is 0, 90, 0.

So, I have the Transforms of the main game object and the second game object, now I need to calculate the amount to rotate per frame, so that the rotation happens in the correct duration.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you maybe add some images that show what happens and then what you would like to have happen instead? That gives us a clearer idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want something moving within a specified time I would recommend to not do it in `Update` but instead use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).
It works like a little temporary `Update` method and is executed each frame until the next `yield`. this is better to maintain and control than the `Update` method.

Then do your rotation using [`Quaternion.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html) or also [`Quaternion.Slerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) depending a bit on your needs

```c#
private IEnumerator RotateOverTime(Transform transformToRotate, Quaternion targetRotation, float duration)
{
    var startRotation = transformToRotate.rotation;

    var timePassed = 0f;
    while(timePassed < duration)
    {
        var factor = timePassed / duration;
        // optional add ease-in and -out
        //factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

        transformToRotate.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, targetRotation, factor);
        // or
        //transformToRotate.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, targetRotation, factor);

        // increae by the time passed since last frame
        timePassed += time.deltaTime;

        // important! This tells Unity to interrupt here, render this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // to be sure to end with exact values set the target rotation fix when done
    transformToRotate.rotation = targetRotation;
}
```

Now in order to start this routine you would call it via `StartCoroutine` like e.g.

```c#
// simply stop any other running routine so you don't get concurrent ones
StopAllCoroutines();
StartCoroutine(transformToRotate, otherTransform.rotation, 3f);
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! It takes account the duration and the target rotation! Thank you sir, you have cured my headache.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) method for this. So, it should be something like this in Update:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, secondTransform.rotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Impossible to reach the target rotation in a given time .. or maybe ever ;)

Answer (score 0):

https://answers.unity.com/questions/765197/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-over-a-set-time.html

The answer for short:

```
 float totalRotationTime = 5.0f;
 float y_degreesPerSecond = go.transform.eulerAngles.y / totalRotationTime;
 float x_degs = go.transform.x/ totalRotationTime;
 //etc...
 go.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x_degs * Time.deltaTime, degreesPerSecond * Time.deltaTime, 0));
```

Comment: what if `Y` is not the only axis to be rotated?

Comment: Then do the same calculations for x and z and replace the first zero with that value, Edited it for you with an example

Comment: or simply do `Vector3 rotationPerSecond = go.transform.eulerAngles / totalRotationTime;` and `go.transform.Rotate(rotationPerSecond * Time.deltaTime);` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the answer given by derHugo, with this update you can define the time and the angle that object will rotate in the given time.

```html
    private IEnumerator RotateOverTime(float duration)
    {
        var timePassed = 0f;
        while (timePassed < duration)
        {
            var factor = timePassed / duration;

            factor = (Mathf.PI / 2) * (Time.deltaTime / duration);
            print("factor: " + factor);

            hedefAraYon = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, hedefYon, factor, 0.0f);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(hedefAraYon, Vector3.back);

            // increae by the time passed since last frame
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

            // important! This tells Unity to interrupt here, render this frame
            // and continue from here in the next frame
            yield return null;
        }        
        
        // donme takılı kalabiliyor, o yüzden 0,5f olarak ayarladım
        if (Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(hedefYon, Vector3.back)) <= 0.5f)
        {
            Vector3 tempRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            tempRotation.x = Mathf.RoundToInt(tempRotation.x);
            tempRotation.y = Mathf.RoundToInt(tempRotation.y);
            tempRotation.z = Mathf.RoundToInt(tempRotation.z);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(tempRotation);
        }

        hareketDurumu = HAREKET_DURUMU.DURUYOR;
        print("Time Passed-Döner OK: " + timePassedOverall);
    }
```